# Where to use @StateObject and ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

I'm learning swiftUI and I'm getting confused in @StateObject and  @ObservableObject when to use them and where to use them.

Comment: There are lots of articles, tutorials, and SO questions about this. Can you clarify what is confusing you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Apple's [Managing Model Data in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app). `ObservedObject` comes from a parent view and `StateObject` instantiates in the `View` that needs it.